# Motion of fluid inside the aircraft drop tank

Tags: c, user-defined-functions, fluent

I have been working on motion of fluid inside the aircraft drop tank. For my initial case, fluid is moving to and fro. For this case I used the following code but is yielding the error.

```
zone_motion.c ..\..\src\zone_motion.c(7) : error C2100: illegal indirection
..\..\src\zone_motion.c(11) : error C2100: illegal indirection 
..\..\src\zone_motion.c(14) : error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type 
..\..\src\zone_motion.c(14) : error C2100: illegal indirection 
..\..\src\zone_motion.c(14) : error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type 
..\..\src\zone_motion.c(14) : error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type
```

How can I modify this code?

```
#include "udf.h"
DEFIINE_ZONE_MOTION(fmotion, omega, axis, origin, velocity, time, dtime)
{
if(time<10)
{
    *omega=10;
}
else
{
    *omega=0;
}
N3V_D(velocity,=,0.01*sin(*omega*time), 0.0, 0.0);
}
```

Comment: zone_motion.c
..\..\src\zone_motion.c(7) : error C2100: illegal indirection
..\..\src\zone_motion.c(11) : error C2100: illegal indirection
..\..\src\zone_motion.c(14) : error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type
..\..\src\zone_motion.c(14) : error C2100: illegal indirection
..\..\src\zone_motion.c(14) : error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type
..\..\src\zone_motion.c(14) : error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type

Comment: Add the error in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

I might not help you, but maybe someone else will find this usefull. I have a working code similar to your problem. The code spins up liniarly the domain and after reaching max omega it holds. Enjoy:

```
#include "udf.h"

DEFINE_ZONE_MOTION(fmotion2,omega,axis,origin,velocity,time,dtime)
{
float omega_max, t_end, ramp, rpm;

omega_max=314.0;
t_end=10.0;
ramp=omega_max / t_end;
velocity[0]=0.0;
velocity[1]=0.0;
velocity[2]=0.0;

origin[0]=-0.1;
origin[1]=-0.1;
origin[2]=0.0;

axis[0]=0.0;
axis[1]=0.0;
axis[2]=1.0;

    if (CURRENT_TIME < t_end) 
    {
    *omega = ramp * CURRENT_TIME;
    //print("Current omega value %fn",*omega);
    }
    else
    {
    *omega = omega_max;
    }
  return;
}
```

Comment: whatever this will useful or not you should only post the appropriate answer to the question and nothing else